# MySQL clustering & JBOSS

Tags: java, mysql, database, jboss, database-cluster

I need to configure JBOSS for MySQL clustering with databases at two different machines (i.e different IPs).

Active-active configuration of db is desired with -

1. Both db to be updated simultaneously
2. Loadbalancing
3. Failover handling - to switch to the other db in case of failure of the 1st db

How do I configure mysql-ds.xml file to achieve all these ? Will it alone solve my problem or any other configuration changes need to be done ?

So far I have tried the following but without much success -

**code sample 1 -**

```
<local-tx-datasource>
            <jndi-name>/abc</jndi-name>
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://ip1:portno1,ip2:portno2/dbname?loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000</connection-url> 
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <user-name>def</user-name>
            <password>defpassword</password>
            <exception-sorter-class-name>path to exception sorter class</exception-sorter-class-name>
    </local-tx-datasource>
```

**code sample 2 -**

```
<local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>/abc</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://ip1:portno1,ip2:portno2/dbname?loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000</connection-url> 
        <url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>
            <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
            <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
            <maxReconnects>0</maxReconnects>
            <initialTimeout>15</initialTimeout>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
            <connection-property name="readOnly">false</connection-property>
            <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>

        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>def</user-name>
        <password>defpassword</password>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>path to exception sorter class</exception-sorter-class-name>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

What more is required ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this only by using mysql-ds.xml datasource file configuration. What you need to do is following.

**Note:** You will have to use mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar and above for database driver. Earlier versions have some bug (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31053) which will pose you many issues so avoid them.
I am providing a snippet for mysql-ds.xml file.

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>DATA_SOURCE_NAME</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://IP1:port1,IP2:port2</connection-url>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    <driver-class>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</driver-class>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>select count(*) from your_table_name</check-valid-connection-sql>
</local-tx-datasource>
```